# keep ROR app running even on exit from shell

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Well to be frank enough this is my first ROR installation in development mode on test server.
i've installed an instance of : https://github.com/sharetribe/sharetribe

I started the server using : `rvmsudo rails server -p 80`
via ssh 
it works absolutely fine.
But as soon as i quit the terminal [mac] the app stopped. Note i'm running this on some server and not on localhost on my machine.

I've worked with node and am aware there re libs like forever to keep the script running even on exit. Is there a simpler way to achieve this in rails app too ?

I got some links for some lib like "God" but It's really hard to understand how to use it.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running it as a daemon:

```
 rvmsudo rails server -p 80 -d &
```

Now the app should be running even if you exit from the shell

Comment: thanks. this worked like charm. i can exit the shell and script still continues to work.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to bypass creating a permanent server for a production website.

Basically, the `rails s` command is really just for development, trying out your code as you write it. It's not suitable for running an actual app to be used in the big, wide world (this is why it doesn't, by default, run on port 80).

If you expect more than one person to use the app at any given time, this will cause unexplained errors when using the `rails s` method.

You need a more heavyweight server application to handle requests which are then passed on to rails.

Typically I would set this up to use apache and the 'passenger' plugin. Which will allow your app to work with multiple requests at once (also, you will have difficulty doing this with an sqlite database, almost any other will handle multiple points of access).

Try looking through the documentation for passenger https://www.phusionpassenger.com/

There are also lots of tutorials online on how to deploy rails apps, here are just a couple:

- https://nathanhoad.net/how-to-ruby-on-rails-ubuntu-apache-with-passenger
- http://wyeworks.com/blog/2009/1/28/setting-up-passenger-in-linux

---

If, for some reason, you want to have this server open, without a terminal, for use by a single user, you could use nohup

```
nohup rails s &
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a quick alternative, you can run `rails s` inside a `screen` (http://linux.die.net/man/1/screen).
First of all install `screen` from your package repository, then:

Start screen typing: `screen`
Run the server: `rails s`
Detach screen and go to your main process: `Press CTRL+a then CTRL+d`
If you want to check the screen later: `screen -r` (on your main process)
If you want to kill the screen: `CTRL+d` (inside the screen process)

Remeber that this is just for test things out, this alternative is not so great for production servers.